# androidTest not running on emulator with Android API below 21

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-testing

I've a set of tests in my project under the classic `androidTest` folder, but when I try to launch them on an emulator running Android API 19 (either by right clicking on the test folder and tapping `run Tests` or by using the gradle command `./gradlew connectedDebugAndroidTest`) only a small subset of those actually run (8 out of 177)

Doing the same but on an emulator running Android API 21 instead run the whole suite! Why does that happen?
I tried to run the gradle command with `--stacktrace --info` and to dump the content of `logcat` to a file but I could not find anything relatable to the issue

Just for clarity, the tests do not fail, they are just not considered for the run, and moreover, if I then select one of the sub-folders (or a single class) of the ones not run and run that specifically, then it runs and the tests inside that folder (or class) pass